# How to install SharePoint Foundation 2010 with SQL server 2012 standard version on windows server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I have to install SharePoint foundation 2010 with SQL server 2012 Standard Version on Windows server 2012

What I have flow the steps:

1. Installed Windows server 2012
2. Installed SQL server 2012 Standard Version
3. Installed SharePoint Foundation 2010(SP1)

But Issue is that SharePoint not picking the right SQL server 2012 Standard Version instance,it always uses the SQL server express instance that is comes with SharePoint SP1 .exe file.

I have tried this activity for 3- 4 times by removing SharePoint and SQL and Repair as well but always all the configuration databases are generated in the SQL express instance.

Did anyone having suggestions or solution will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: still no answer? if yes please mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are choosing Standalone installation and this option will always install SharePoint Data Bases in SQL Express.

When installing SharePoint you must choose **Server Farm** installation (even if SP and SQL are on the same server) at the second screen after accepting licence terms, some screens later you will be able to choose the SQL instance.

Here are some guides that may help you, however I recommend you to search more information:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287960(v=office.14).aspx

http://mahedee.net/installing-sharepoint-foundation-2010-step-by-step/

https://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/install-sharepoint-2010-with-ms-sql-server-2012-on-windows-server-2012/

Required accounts:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662519(v=office.14).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288210(v=office.14).aspx